# trigger jQuery functions only once

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which displays a message in the console log only once the following conditions have been met...

1. Viewport is wider than 1250px
2. User is near the bottom of the page
3. User resizes the browser to make wider

My code is this...

```
function checkSize(){
      if($(window).width() > 1250 && $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 700) {
        console.log('hello');
      }
    }

    checkSize();
    $(window).scroll(checkSize);
    $(window).resize(checkSize);
```

You can see a demo here... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zAxHb

The problem with this is as you scroll up and down and resize a few times, it fires multiple times. I only want it to fire once, and then always remain.

Any way how I can do this?

Comment: *"and then always remain"*, what does that mean? So it seems you don't to call the function while the conditions are met (apart from the first time). What if the conditions change? Do you want to fire it again when the conditions are met again?

Comment: Sorry, yes you are correct. Once the function has fired for the first time, I do not want it to continuously fire. If the conditions change, then no, it should not fire again, as the message will already have loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you could simply undbind the event handler after the condition was met:

```
function checkSize(){
  if($(window).width() > 1250 && $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 700) {
    console.log('hello');
    $(window).off('scroll resize', checkSize);
  }
}

$(window).on('scroll resize', checkSize);
checkSize();
```

Comment: perfect! this is exactly what I was after

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Felix Kling's answer:

For future development of the page, it might be wise to namespace the the event in $(window) and then disable those events only, so the other functionality (if exists) for the $(window) scroll and resize events won't get disabled:

```
$(window).on('scroll.sizeChecker resize.sizeChecker', checkSize);
```

and to disable:

```
$(window).off('.sizeChecker');
```

Answer (score 0):

This function may be used to fire something once, with an optional delay.

```
var executeOnce = (function (fn, delay) {
  var executed = false;
  return function (/* args */) {
    var args = arguments;
    if (!executed) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        fn.apply(null, args); // preserve arguments
      }, delay);
      executed = true;
    }
  };
});
```